# Parity of spherical harmonics

Tags: special-functions, mathematical-physics, legendre-polynomials, spherical-harmonics, parity

I would like to prove that $Y_{\ell m}(-\mathbf{r}) = (-1)^\ell\, Y_{\ell m}(\mathbf{r})$. In this formula, $Y_{\ell m}$ are the spherical harmonics given by
\begin{equation}
Y_{\ell m}(\theta, \varphi) = \sqrt{\frac{2\ell + 1}{4\pi}\frac{(\ell-|m|)!}{(\ell+|m|)!}}\, P_\ell^m(\cos\theta)e^{\mathrm{i}m\varphi}.
\end{equation}
For the associated Legendre polynomials, I follow the convention
\begin{equation}
P_\ell^m(x) = \frac{(-1)^m}{2^\ell \ell!} (1-x^2)^{\frac{m}{2}}\frac{\mathrm{d}^{\ell+m}}{\mathrm{d}x^{\ell+m}}(x^2-1)^\ell.
\end{equation}

I already figured out that $\mathbf{r}\to -\mathbf{r}$ corresponds to $\theta\to \pi-\theta$ and $\varphi\to \pi+\varphi$ in spherical coordinates. This yields
\begin{align}
\cos\theta&\to -\cos\theta\\
e^{\mathrm{i}m\varphi}&\to (-1)^m\, e^{\mathrm{i}m\varphi},
\end{align}
but I do not see how $P_\ell^m(-x) = (-1)^{\ell+m}\, P_\ell^m(x)$. To me, it seems like it should not change anything as $(-x)^2=x^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Remember you are also taking the derivative, so you must apply the change rule, e.g, call $z = -x$

\begin{eqnarray}
P_\ell^m(z) &=& P_\ell^m(-x) \\
&=& \frac{(-1)^m}{2^\ell \ell!} (1-z^2)^{\frac{m}{2}}\frac{\mathrm{d}^{\ell+m}}{\mathrm{d}z^{\ell+m}}(z^2-1)^\ell  \\
&=& \frac{(-1)^m}{2^\ell \ell!} (1-(-x)^2)^{\frac{m}{2}}\frac{\mathrm{d}^{\ell+m}}{\mathrm{d}(-x)^{\ell+m}}((-x)^2-1) \\
&=& (-1)^{\ell + m} P_\ell^m(x)
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Thanks! Why can you not just replace $x$ with $-x$ behind the derivative? Could you give me a more detailed explanation?

Comment: @physicist23 Do you mean something like


$$
\frac{{\rm d}}{-{\rm d} x^{\ell + m}}
$$

?

Comment: No, I mean $((-x)^2-1)^\ell$ is just the same as $(x^2-1)^\ell$ and I thought I do not need to care for the derivative as $f=g$ implies $f'=g'$.

Comment: @physicist23 You're correct, $f=g$ implies $f'=g'$ *but* this is not what you're doing, you're calculating the derivative w.r.t another variable, namely $-x$

Comment: @caverac Do you mean $\frac{{\rm (d)^{l+m}}}{{\rm d} (-x)^{\ell + m}}$ = $(-1)^{l+m}\frac{{\rm (d)^{l+m}}}{{\rm d } (x)^{\ell + m}}$ ?

Comment: @ryan1 Indeed, you can get that from applying the chain rule $l + m$ times